# Why email sender in env staging server not update if I use shouldqueue on notification laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, notifications, laravel-5.3, laravel-notification

I use laravel 5.3

If class on the notification like this :

```
class UserRegistered extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
```

I edit email sender in env, then I check send email, the email sender not update

If class on the notification like this :

```
class UserRegistered extends Notification
```

I edit email sender in env, then I check send email, the email sender update

Why email sender in env staging server not update if I use shouldqueue on laravel?

Comment: what do you mean ' i edit sender in env ' ... have you restarted the queue workers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the mail config file

```
config/mail.php
```

then check that section

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

did you set those variables in the .env file?

Comment: @arsbadke, Yes, of course. You try to read my question carefully

Comment: Ok, please try to overwrite the default values (hello@example.com, Example) directly in the config/mail.php file.

'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'your@address.com'),

 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Your Name'),